# Grouping attributes based on other field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, statistics

How do I group my attributes and show total area of districts or number of blocks for each contract?

I tried to use groupby clause in select by attribute tool but it did not work.

I work in ArcGIS Pro. Moreover, I would like to show it on the map with a proper symbology

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each attribute row in a feature layer represents a geometry(Point, Line, or Polygon). Herewith your concern the districts are associated with multiple contract agreement types. As @PolyGeo shared you can easily get the required outcome using summarize, but that could not be used when you want this for a display.

So, one possible workflow you can follow is to create a multipart feature layer out of the existing unique features(single part).

This can be achieved using the [Dissolve Tool in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm):

**Multiple State Names representing Population:**
[image]

**Pairwise Dissolve Tool:**
[image]

**Resulting Layer**
[image]

**Note:** This process will create a new layer, and you can use it for symbolizing features accordingly.